# Does Lagrange Multipliers method provide a way to classify relative minimum and maximum points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In all the problems I've seen about Lagrange's multipliers method they always ask for absolute minimum and maximum points, but what about relative ones?
In this example:

$f(x,y)=x^2+3y$ subject to the restriction $x^2+y^2=5$
the method provides the following points $ P=(0, \sqrt{5})$
$ Q=(0, -\sqrt{5})$, $ R=(\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$
$ S=(-\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$

so
$f(P)= 3\sqrt{5} \approx6.69$

$f(Q)= -3\sqrt{5}\approx-6.69$

$f(R)= \frac{29}{4}=7.25$

$f(S)= \frac{29}{4}=7.25$

So one concludes that Q is a minimum point and R and S are maximum points
but how do I determine the nature of P: relative maximum, relative minimum ?

A graph of the function tells me it should be a relative minimum (the intersection curve bends down in a neighbordhood of point P):

[image]

Besides I tried solving it by studying the single-variable function $h(y)=
5-y^2+3y$  which I got by plugging in the restriction into f. By making $h'(y)=0$ I found $y=3/2$  and considering $-\sqrt{5}\leq y \leq \sqrt{5}$
to be it's domain to stay in the restriction,  $y=\sqrt{5}$ and $y=-\sqrt{5}$ are also possible extrema points.
Plugging in this values into the restriction $x^2+y^2=5$, yields the corresponding x-components, so the same P,Q ,R and S points found with the first method. 
Then, comparing the values of h(y) in the y-components of these  points:

$h(\sqrt{5})=3\sqrt{5}=f(P)$

$h(-\sqrt{5})=-3\sqrt{5}=f(Q)$

$h(\frac{3}{2})= \frac{29}{4}=f(R)=f(S)$

Q is found again to be a minimum point and R ans S to be maximum points.
But now I could use second-derivative test for P:
 $h''(y)=-2 < 0$ ,  for any $y$ and so $P$ should be a local maximum, in contradiction with graph that shows it to be local minimum, What is this second method not working and how do both  methods determine P is a  relative minimum?

Comment: by the way, You've written $f(x,y)$ so are we to assume $f$ is defined on $\Bbb{R}^2$? because if this is the case, then your picture is $3$-dimensional and hence doesn't match up with what you said. But if you do indeed consider $f$ as a function of $3$ variables $f: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}$, $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 3y$ then your picture is correct, but you haven't found all the critical points. Because your work only determines the $x,y$ coordinates of the critical point, but it doesn't constrain the $z$-coordinate. So, in $3$ dimensions, you will have in addition, one critical point for each $z$

Comment: yes on R^2, I just draw the cylinder , to see the points of the surface f , to which it is restricted

Comment: by the way, an alternative approach to this problem is to simply parametrize the circle by $t \mapsto (\sqrt{5} \cos t, \sqrt{5} \sin t)$. If you were asked explicitly to solve using Lagrange multipliers, then of course this is not the way. But if you have the freedom to use any method, I believe this parametrization will give a very quick method of finding critical points of $f$ (when restricted to the circle) and classify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative test tells you about the type of critical point on the *interior* of the search interval.  Let's temporarily set aside the source of the equation and just try to solve

> Extremize $h(y) = 5 - y^2 + 3y$ on $[-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}]$.

The second derivative tells you whether an interior critical point, the one at $y = 3/2$ is a local minimum, local maximum, neither, or unresolved.  It *cannot* speak to the endpoints because the first derivative is not (generally) zero at the endpoints.  As far as the first derivative is concerned we could find even lower points by pushing just outside the search interval.

Additionally, notice that you are looking at the first and second derivatives in the $y$ direction.  The $y$-axis in your diagram is the green one.  At the points $P$ and $Q$, infinitesimal displacements in the $y$ direction leave the surface of the cylinder.  It may well be that the second derivative in a direction that is disallowed by the constraint is negative, but the intersection curve you see on the constraint cylinder is running in the $x$ direction at $P$ and $Q$.  To understand their behaviour, you need to be taking derivatives in the $x$-direction, which means eliminating $y$ between the objective function and the constraint and extremizing this new single variable objective function.

Expanding on this last.  From the constraint, either $y = \sqrt{5 - x^2}$ or $y = - \sqrt{5 - x^2}$.  In the first case, $h_1(x) = x^2 + 3\sqrt{5 - x^2}$,

[image: h1(x)]

$h_1'(x) = 2x - \frac{3x}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$, and $h_1'(x) = 0$ when $x \in \{ -\sqrt{11}/2, 0, \sqrt{11}/2 \}$ where $h_1'(\pm \sqrt{11}/2) < 0$ and $h'(0) > 0$.  This finds your points $R$, $P$, and $S$ and assigns the correct local extremization to each of them.  Switching to $h_2(x) = x^2 - 3\sqrt{5 - x^2}$,

[image: h2(x)]

only $h_2'(0) = 0$ and $h_2''(0) > 0$, correctly identifying $Q$ as a local minimum.    We should also check $h_1(\pm \sqrt{5})$ and $h_2(\pm \sqrt{5})$ because calculus does not generally tell you about the endpoints (consider the extremization of a nonconstant line -- the derivative is never zero and the extrema occur at the endpoints of the search interval).  The first derivative is mute on these points because infinitesimal displacement from these points in the $x$ direction (along the red axis in your picture) leaves the constraint cylinder, so the first and second derivatives in $x$ tell you nothing about these points.

Comment: Just a clarification, you said..." the intersection curve you see on the constraint cylinder is running in the x direction at P and Q", if I consider a neighborhood of the instersection curve, it has a component in both the x and y direction, so you can't say it is running in the x direction, can you?

Comment: This is an excellent answer which addresses the need to be careful with boundary points. I realized that this was the issue with OP's work, but I just didn't know exactly how to phrase it properly. +1

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver : The tangent to the intersection curve at $P$ is parallel to the red ($x$) axis.  Likewise, the tangent to the intersection curve at $Q$.  The derivatives live in the tangents.

Answer (score 1):

There is a second derivative test for constrained problems, based on the *bordered Hessian matrix*. You can find the statement in my book *Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds* in problem 34 on p. 225. [This handout](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf) which I found with a search may do the trick for you.

Comment: thanks for the handout